# pressing ok/cancel on options menu in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I`ve created a custom visual studio 2015 options menu showing text boxes, using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166195.aspx.

I`m trying to save the text box value when a user presses OK.

The problem is that the only way I can find to save the data in the text box is using events relating to the text box itself, such as TextChanged event.

Does anyone know how I can do stuff when the user presses OK/CANCEL on the options menu?

Thanks :)

Comment: Are you saying that you are unable to handle the buttons' events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override the [OnApply](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.dialogpage.onapply.aspx) method from the DialogPage class to save the data. See the [DialogPage class documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.dialogpage.aspx) for more details and other relevant methods like OnClosed.